# Magento MySQL tuning

Tags: mysql, apache, magento

I have been noticing quite a bit of latancy with my Magento store, we are running a Dedicated Virtual server with 4GB of RAM. When I asked my host about these problems I was told the below statement. Could you offer assistance on what specifically needs to be tweaked in MySQL for optimal performance?

> However, it appears that using Magento is causing a problem. Magento
>   requires significant MySQL tuning to keep running properly. I suggest
>   you work with a sysadmin to tune the server to suit Magentos very
>   large resource requirements.

Comment: There is a quite a bit to this subject. Much of it is also dependent on your workload. You will probably be looking at memory and cache settings based on system counters within mysql. There are quite a few memory/cache related settings and they affect different parts of your performance.

Comment: Again, the wrong angle of view, no matter what application you have, you have to dig into tuning process. wordpress, typo, oscommerce, forums, etc... enough to speculate on the word "Magento".

  run these tools 
[**mysqlreport**](http://hackmysql.com/scripts/mysqlreport)
[**mysqltuner**](http://mysqltuner.pl)

and you will see whats wrong with your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento has a few white papers [that cover the basics](http://www.magentocommerce.com/whitepaper/).

There's an old thread on the Magento forums that, while containing out of date information, will point you towards the MySQL configuration fields that you'd [need to tweak](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/4168/).

Seriously consider using a hosting partner that specializes [in Magento hosting](http://www.magentocommerce.com/partners/hosting/).  If you read between the lines your host is telling you they don't want your business.

Comment: Thanks for the help Alan, will check this out. I agree that I need to move providers, just hoping for a short-term solution while I sort out a longer term move.

Comment: +1. Just pick a host with Magento experience. By far the majority of issues I see with our clients who host externally are because they are using an inexperienced web host not familiar with Magento. It's often not an issue on small sites with only a few hundred products in a handful of categories, but for multi-site setups with thousands of products across dozens of categories, the poorly performing web host will really start to stand out.

Comment: @LouisW understood.  innodb_buffer_pool_size and innodb_additional_mem_pool_size are good starting places — you need to tell MySQL it's allowed to use all that RAM you have.  That said, I know a lot of VPS hypervisors (the software that controls virtualization) are configured in a way that makes performance tuning a Magento store futile, and hosts are going to be wary of changing their hypervisor configurations for a single client.